# Weird SASS behavior when calculating values with units

Tags: sass

... at least it seems weird to me, but maybe I just don't get what's going on.

Given the following SASS code:

```
$test: 2rem;
@warn $test / 2;
@warn 2 / $test;
```

I get the following result:

```
1rem  // that is what I am expecting
1/rem // huh?
```

Why is that? Bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you expecting 2 / 2rem to be equal to 1rem? In algebra, 2 / 2a = 1/a. So 2 / 2rem = 1/rem. This is not a bug, but the result is an invalid css value.

Comment: @trevor, in this case 2rem / 2 won't work either. But SASS is trying to correctly take the unit values into account. But if it does, both results should be identical

Answer (score 0):

Type the following code in at [sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/):

```
$test: 2rem;
//@error $test / 2;
//@error 2 / $test;
//@warn $test / 2;
//@warn 2 / $test;
```

Note that I have made a correction to your code, as $test = 2rem is not valid.

When you uncomment the first @error line, it correctly reports a value of 1rem.

When you uncomment the second @error line, it correctly reports a value of 1/rem.

When you uncomment the first @warn line, you get no output because the expression evaluates to a valid css value of 1rem.

When you uncomment the second @warn line, you get the following warning message: **1/rem isn't a valid CSS value.**

The warning is there to tell you that you did something wrong. It is not a bug in sass.

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo in my code, thanks for the correction. Anyways, still not sure if that is not a bug. I mean, of course  "1/rem" is no valid CSS value, but why does the calculation come up with such a result in the first place?